# upload image django rest framework corrupted

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the next view to upload a image but the generated image is corrupted.

```
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FileUploadParser,)

    def uploadFile(self, up_file):
        if not os.path.exists(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER):
            os.mkdir(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER)
        file_name = '{}.jpeg'.format(uuid.uuid4())

        destination = open(
          '{}/{}'.format(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER, file_name), 'wb+')
        for chunk in up_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close()

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        self.uploadFile(file_obj)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like this

```
    def uploadFile(self, f):
        filename = f.name
        redington_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/yourpath/'
        if not os.path.exists(redington_path):
            os.makedirs(redington_path)
        BASE_PATH = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/yourpath/'
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, vendorid))
        with open(BASE_PATH  + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
```

you need get files from **request.FILES['file']**

```
    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        self.uploadFile(file_obj)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: dont raise raise exception but generated file is corrupted.

Comment: can you please look at this one http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Django/Python_Django_Image_Files_Uploading_Example.php

Answer (score 0):

Need to add set `format=jpeg` and file_name should be `up_file.name`
    class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
        parser_classes = (parsers.FileUploadParser,)

```
    def uploadFile(self, up_file):
        if not os.path.exists(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER):
            os.mkdir(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER)
        up_file.name
        file_name = up_file.name

        destination = open('{}/{}'.format(BUILDING_PHOTOS_FOLDER, file_name), 'wb+')
        for chunk in up_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close()

    def put(self, request, filename, format='jpeg'):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        self.uploadFile(file_obj)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve sending the image as raw binary from frontend.